# How to find the cause of a 100% CPU usage on an iPhone App when i use ionic2

Tags: ionic2, iphone-5, ios10.3

when I click button quickly, which cause iPhone5 higher cpu usage?
why it happened?
code following:

```
<div>{{tempstrng}}</div>
<button tappable (touchend)="change()">add 0</button>

public change (){
   this.tempstring +='0';
}
```

Comment: You can debug it using Safari from your Mac OS, as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689270/debug-ionic-app-on-ios

Comment: Does it only happen on the device or also when you test it in your browser?

Comment: browser and android is ok ,only has problem in iphone5

Comment: did you get a solution for this ?