# APP only works the first time on ios

Tags: ios, typescript, ionic-framework

im having a problem since I’m trying to test my app on iOS.

The first time I install my app on an emulator/device the app works correctly. But if I close my app, and open again the app don’t work anymore and get stuck on the white screen forever.

My `ionic info` is:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.14.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.14.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.2
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Node  : v8.7.0
    npm   : 5.4.2 
    OS    : macOS Sierra
    Xcode : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235 

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I tried so many solutions, like remove and add de platforms, remove and add de plugin one by one. The app works on Android perfectly, but on iOS I have this problem.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

We can debug ios application

```
ionic emulate ios -lc
```

Which runs app using simulator and outputs console logs and errors to terminal with live reloading.

> There are three primary options.
>
> 1. Debug using Safari. This is good for debugging a hybrid app, but
>      cannot tell you output related to native plugins.
>      http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787
> 2. Open the project and build to device in Xcode. This shows the output of the entire device http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide
> 3. Debug with Ionic CLI. Using ionic run ios -l -c -s with the flags will use live reload and print the logs to the console. http://ionicframework.com/blog/live-reload-all-things-ionic-cli/

From: [Debug Ionic app on IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689270/debug-ionic-app-on-ios)

Comment: I can debug IOS application too, but the thing, it's working only the first time. If I shutdown the app and open again Ionic Framework get stucked on Splashscreen, but don't give any error