# How to debug real iOS device from windows machine in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am working on ionic application. I am able to debug app in real android device.

So, is it possible to debug ionic app in iPhone by connecting it through *USB* cable from *CPU*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug Ionic app on IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689270/debug-ionic-app-on-ios)

Comment: Install MAC OS on your Virtual Machine and try to debug it. 
p.s I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 1):

You require an iPhone and a mac with XCode installed.

> If you are building for iOS, you’ll need to sign up for an Apple
>   Developer account to test as a native app on an iPhone or iPad.
>   Unfortunately, this costs $99 per year (don’t blame us!). Once you
>   have an account and you have set up Xcode with your certificates to
>   enable device testing, you’ll want to open the Xcode project from
>   `platforms/ios/` and do your testing from Xcode.

[Source](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html)

As you have mentioned you do have an iPhone and Mac with XCode, see the steps below:

1. Run `ionic cordova prepare ios`
2. Copy across your `platform/ios` folder to your Mac
3. Open the XCode project on your Mac that is located in the `platform/ios` folder.
4. Select a device or target simulator in XCode and then click on the play button to start debugging.

Comment: I have real device and mac machine with Xcode. How do I connect my VS Code IDE(Windows machine) to mac machine.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 - I have updated my answer with steps to run it.